# Images on category view are stretched, cannot work out how to fix

Tags: category, theme, image

I have read several posts online how to fix this but they seem to be out dated, the code they are telling me to edit looks different on mine, the post was from 2008.

See image 1. The madeira herring image is stretched.
Image 2 displays how it should really look.

How can I fix this?!

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Nathan,please use the magento `resize` function which create correct image for different size of products .You have try to increase product image size(width and height) using css yo HTML element .

**Example:**

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')
            ->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(YourWidth,YourHeight); ?>
```

See at http://turnkeye.com/blog/images-resize-in-magento/

Comment: Sorry - I cannot see on that article where to find the file to edit which has this code in?

Comment: have you check at list.phtml at app/design/frontent/youraPackage/YourTemaplet/template/cataloh/product/list/phtml and find code <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(300,300) ?> change something at ...

Comment: I cannot find that exact line, how about this?

Comment: <?php //Product Image ?>
            <div class="product-image-wrapper grid12-4 mobile-grid-half">

                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image" style="max-width:<?php echo $imgWidth; ?>px;">
                    <img src="<?php echo $helpImg->getImg($_product, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, 'small_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                    
                    <?ph.....

Comment: nathan,you have using customer magento function getting the images...that why you could not find my code

Comment: use 
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($imgWidth, $imgHeight) ?> 
instead of 
<?php echo $helpImg->getImg($_product, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, 'small_image'); ?>